# UnsupportedClassVersion 52.0 error though I recompiled class under JDK5 in Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle

I have a strange situation: I want to switch one class in library, so I created jar with this class and I loaded this to Oracle - and this threw error about too new class version (and that was true, I didn't noticed that I compiled it with JDK8).

So I recompiled it with JDK5 and loaded again, but... it throws the same error again, `UnsupportedClassVersionError`.

I checked in `SYS.ALL_JAVA_CLASSES` and this classes has major 49.0 number.

I tried to load all library, and it didn't help. I tried to drop this classes and load again, drop all library and load again - nothing changed.

In my opinion this error sholudn't happens any more, but DB still throws it.

Any ideas why it happens? And what should I do?

P.S.
Sorry for terrible english...

Comment: Have you tried searching the Oracle server's file system for old copies of the class or its containing JAR file?  Have you tried restarting the Oracle services ... in case this some kind of "stickiness"

Comment: how can I find this old copies? Restarting instatnce could delete this old copies? This is what I think, that DB still using some old files...

Comment: 1) Use the `find` command.  2) If the problem is that Oracle is using old files, then a restart probably won't help.  The restart is for the case where Oracle has somehow loaded the old file into memory ... or something ... and is refusing to refresh them.

Comment: So how to delete this old copies?

Comment: Use `rm`?  That's how you delete files.  Of course you need to find them first; e.g. using `find`.  (If you don't know how to do that, read the `man` entry for `find` or Google for some examples.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. One class from other library, which was using my class, remembered that it was too high class version. Load and resolve this other library helped.

Answer (score -1):

[Class version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) numbering is something different from the external java version.

```
major version number of the class file format being used.
J2SE 8 = 52 (0x34 hex),
J2SE 7 = 51 (0x33 hex),
J2SE 6.0 = 50 (0x32 hex),
J2SE 5.0 = 49 (0x31 hex),
JDK 1.4 = 48 (0x30 hex),
JDK 1.3 = 47 (0x2F hex),
JDK 1.2 = 46 (0x2E hex),
JDK 1.1 = 45 (0x2D hex).
```

So 52 stems from java 8. Congratulations.

Comment: Bum my question is why database says that class are compiled with JDK8, while I compiled them with JDK5.